# Tobit or OLS question

Tags: least-squares, tobit-regression

My dependent variable is mostly continuous and positive, but has a modest number of zeros (10% of the sample). The results from tobit and ols are very similar. How can I formally compare the tobit and ols results? I think that I should be using ols, because tobit doesn't change anything.

Comment: Compare is pretty vague. Do you want to test equality of effects of explanatory variables on the latent or actual outcome? Do you want to test if the tobit is appropriate (normality, homoskedasticity, same DGP for zero and above zero)? Do you want to see which model fits the data better?

Comment: Which model fits the data better as Dimitriy suggested is a good approach. See which model minimizes mean squared error using 10-fold cross validation.

Comment: You need to find out what the "real life meaning" is of you zero's. Only use tobit if you find that you are dealing with a censored dependent variable.